# Application is not communicating with api while building apk in REACT NATIVE

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, mobile-development

I'm diving into React Native and could use some guidance. I've encountered an issue where my app runs smoothly on my emulator, and even after installing the debug APK on my physical device, everything seems to work fine. However, when it comes to communication with APIs, my app hits a roadblock.

I've built the APK using `cd android` && `./gradlew assembledebug` Any seasoned React Native developers out there who've faced a similar challenge?

Your assistance and insights would be immensely appreciated!

can anyone help me for this issue i am stuck